# In Rivendell, did Saruman try to use his "Voice" on Elrond, Galadriel and Gandalf?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, saruman

In *[The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903624/)*, when the company arrive to Rivendell, Gandalf is asked to attend a *surprise* reunion with Elrond, Galadriel and Saruman the White. Saruman then opposes himself to Gandalf's involvement with the Dwarves and his plan to get rid of Smaug. Gandalf then reveals his concerns about the Necromancer, but Saruman is skeptical, not believing the Necromancer to be a true threat and minimizes the danger.

Was this speech an attempt from him to utilize his power known as "*The Voice of Saruman*"?

Comment: Probably not, because Saruman can be very persuasive when he wants to, but he doesn't manage to persuade Gandalf or Galadriel. (Who have no reason to suspect treachery, unlike in the events of _The Two Towers_!)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Highly unlikely for two reasons :

1. Elrond, Galadriel and Gandalf were all far too powerful within themselves to fall under Saruman's spells.
2. Saruman didn't align with Sauron until a long time after *The Hobbit's* events took place and had no reason to convince them that the Necromancer was not Sauron.

> Once he was as great as his fame made him. His knowledge was deep, his thought was subtle, and his hands marvelously skilled; and he had a power over the minds of others. The wise he could persuade, and the smaller folk he could daunt. That power he certainly still keeps. There are not many in Middle-earth that I should say were safe, if they were left alone to talk with him, even now when he has suffered a defeat. **Gandalf, Elrond, Galadriel**, perhaps, now his wickedness has been laid bare, but very few others.
>
> *Aragorn talking to Legolas and Gimli as they enter Orthanc with Gandalf, King Theoden and Eomer to speak with Saruman.* [Source](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Saruman)

It's highly likely that Saruman was simply skeptical that a *Necromancer* existed, as he believed Sauron had been defeated forever:

> Gandalf talks with the White Council (Elrond, Galadriel, and Saruman the White) about his involvement with the Dwarves, explaining the presence Radagast encountered and expresses mild suspicion that this necromancer is the Dark Lord. The others are skeptical, believing Sauron to have been defeated forever, and that this necromancer is not a true threat.
>   [Source](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/The_Hobbit%3a_An_Unexpected_Journey)

Comment: Any opposition from Saruman to overthrowing the Necromancer was (at least a few decades later) due to Saruman searching for the One Ring's resting place and not wanting that search to be disturbed

Comment: @SSumner Indeed, but at the time frame we're talking about in *The Hobbit*, the One Rings whereabouts were still unknown and therefore could not have factored into Sarumans opinion on the Necromancer, as per question.

Comment: *now his wickedness has been laid bare* This implies to me that before this event, even they were susceptible. Also, you're drawing form a *fan* wikia, which are not known for their accuracy.

Comment: Perhaps he just likes to be contrary to Gandalf... there has been a potential for rivalry there.

Comment: @Pureferret That's not my understanding of the meaning of now his wickedness has been laid bare. It implies that they would not have been under any threat from Saruman before. Indeed, he was the Head of the White Council, why would Elrond, Galdriel and Gandalf been under threat from him?

Comment: @spiceyokooko: Because he has at that point sided with,  Sauron or at least is aiming to decieve them

Comment: @Pureferret Saruman hasn't sided with Sauron at that point in Rivendell because the One Ring hasn't yet been found. He only sides with Sauron because he want's the ring for himself.

Comment: Acrually, it's clearly stated in the Unfinished Tales that Saruman's objections to attacking Dol Guldur were based on his wish to find the One, and that he'd been looking for it for a hundred years at the time of *The Hobbit* - see the answer to this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/what-was-the-earliest-point-at-which-saruman-knew-of-the-one-ring-not-being-lost

Comment: My understanding is that the Voice is not a power that Saruman switches on or off at will, but rather an innate capability that's effectively "always on", but that he sometimes focusses.

Answer (score 10):

It's plausible that Saruman was already evil during the events of The Hobbit. Treebeard's explanation of Saruman to Pippin and Merry is indeed curious (emphasis/bold mine):

> [Wizards] appeared first after the Great Ships came over the Sea, but
>   if they came with the Ships I never can tell. Saruman was reckoned
>   great among them, I believe. **He gave up wandering about and minding
>   the affairs of Men and Elves, some time ago**--you would call it a
>   very long time ago . . . He was very quiet to begin with, but his fame
>   began to grow. **He was chosen to be the head of the White Council,
>   they say; but that did not turn out too well. I wonder now if even
>   then Saruman was not turning to evil ways** . . . I used to talk to
>   him. There was a time when he was always walking about my woods. He
>   was polite in those days, always asking my leave (at least when he met
>   me); and always eager to listen. **I told him many things that he
>   would have never have found out by himself; but he never repaid me in
>   like kind. I cannot remember that he ever told me anything**. And he
>   got more and more like that; his face, as I remember it--I have not
>   seen it for many a day--became like windows in a stone wall: windows
>   with shutters inside. **I think that I now understand what he is up
>   to. He is plotting to become a Power**.

Two things. Treebeard hasn't seen Saruman in a long time--which when Treebeard says a long time, HE MEANS IT! And, Saruman was already corrupt from Treebeard's description. So, it's plausible that he would want Sauron on the chessboard, so to speak, to create a situation where he could be the one who might "become a Power."

EDIT: I suppose what I mean is that Saruman vying for power could be spotted and stopped. The Necromancer, however, would be a diversion! And, it worked---Gandalf was caught off guard when he traveled to Saruman only to be imprisoned atop Orthanc.

Answer (score 4):

At the time of *The Hobbit* Saruman had sent servants to search the *Gladden Fields* west of *Mirkwood*, so yes, he was already 'evil'. Beforehand he had already compelled the Council of the Wise not to assault *Dol Guldor*, fearing that it might indeed be Sauron and henceforth accelerated his search efforts of the *Great River of Anduin* up to the *Gladden Fields* for the *One Ring*.